# change password page issue in dart + flutter + firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I'm doing my first project in flutter and I faced some issues. One of them about change password page, when I write the old and new password and submit it. I log out to test it so I login but it gave me that Invalid password. I tried the new and old password and give me the same error.
Here is my code:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProfilePageState createState() => _ProfilePageState();
}

class _ProfilePageState extends State<ProfilePage> {
  final _oldPasswordController = TextEditingController();
  final _newPasswordController = TextEditingController();
  final _confirmPasswordController = TextEditingController();

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  bool _obscureText = true;

  String encryptPassword(String password) {
    final bytes = utf8.encode(password);
    final hash = sha256.convert(bytes);
    return hash.toString();
  }

  Future<void> _changePassword() async {
    if (_isPasswordSame()) {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Error'),
            content:
                Text('New password must be different from the old password'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              ElevatedButton(
                child: Text('OK'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      );
      return;
    }
    try {
      final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
      final oldCredential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(
        email: user.email!,
        password: _oldPasswordController.text,
      );
      await user.reauthenticateWithCredential(oldCredential);
      final newEncryptedPassword = encryptPassword(_newPasswordController.text);
      await user.updatePassword(newEncryptedPassword);
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Success'),
            content: Text('Password changed successfully'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              ElevatedButton(
                child: Text('OK'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      );
      _oldPasswordController.clear();
      _newPasswordController.clear();
      _confirmPasswordController.clear();
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (error) {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Error'),
            content: Text(error.message!),
            actions: <Widget>[
              ElevatedButton(
                child: Text('OK'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Profile'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'Change Password',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5!,
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                TextFormField(
                  controller: _oldPasswordController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock),
                    suffixIcon: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(
                        _obscureText ? Icons.visibility_off : Icons.visibility,
                        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          _obscureText = !_obscureText;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                    labelText: 'Old Password',
                  ),
                  obscureText: _obscureText,
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value!.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Please enter your old password';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                TextFormField(
                  controller: _newPasswordController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock),
                    suffixIcon: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(
                        _obscureText ? Icons.visibility_off : Icons.visibility,
                        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          _obscureText = !_obscureText;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                    labelText: 'New Password',
                  ),
                  obscureText: _obscureText,
                  validator: validatePass,
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                TextFormField(
                  controller: _confirmPasswordController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock),
                    suffixIcon: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(
                        _obscureText ? Icons.visibility_off : Icons.visibility,
                        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          _obscureText = !_obscureText;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                    labelText: 'Confirm Password',
                  ),
                  obscureText: _obscureText,
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value!.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Please enter your confirm password';
                    }
                    if (value != _newPasswordController.text) {
                      return 'Passwords do not match';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: Text('Change Password'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                      showDialog(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (BuildContext context) {
                          return AlertDialog(
                            title: Text('Confirm Password Change'),
                            content: Text(
                                'Are you sure you want to change your password?'),
                            actions: <Widget>[
                              ElevatedButton(
                                child: Text('Cancel'),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                },
                              ),
                              ElevatedButton(
                                child: Text('Confirm'),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                  _changePassword();
                                },
                              ),
                            ],
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  bool _isPasswordSame() {
    final oldPassword = _oldPasswordController.text;
    final newPassword = _newPasswordController.text;
    return oldPassword == newPassword;
  }

  String? validatePass(String? formPass) {
    if (formPass == null || formPass.isEmpty)
      return 'Password section is required';

    String pattern =
        r'^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[!@#\$&*~]).{8,}$';
    RegExp regex = RegExp(pattern);
    if (!regex.hasMatch(formPass))
      return '''
    Password must include at least 8 characters,
    include an uppercase letter, number and symbol.
  ''';
    return null;
  }
}
```